# Cursor: Invalid Statement in fillWindow() when calling forceLoad() on CursorLoader using SqliteCursorLoader

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter, commonsware-cwac

I'm doing a ListView in a fragment using loaders, ActionBarSherlock and SqliteCursorLoader. The ListView basically shows a list of dates and GPS coordinates. The problem comes in when I reload the ListView upon clicking of a button to go forward and back in time and show the relevant data.

I'm getting a cursor error (sometimes) when trying to forceLoad():

```
05-07 11:42:35.446: E/Cursor(9470): Invalid statement in fillWindow()
05-07 11:42:35.446: D/Row Count(9470): 0
05-07 11:42:35.467: D/AndroidRuntime(9470): Shutting down VM
05-07 11:42:35.467: W/dalvikvm(9470): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
05-07 11:42:35.467: E/AndroidRuntime(9470): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-07 11:42:35.477: E/AndroidRuntime(9470): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
05-07 11:42:35.477: E/AndroidRuntime(9470):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:314)
05-07 11:42:35.477: E/AndroidRuntime(9470):     at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.swapCursor(CursorAdapter.java:344)
05-07 11:42:35.477: E/AndroidRuntime(9470):     at android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.swapCursor(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:326)
05-07 11:42:35.477: E/AndroidRuntime(9470):     at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.changeCursor(CursorAdapter.java:315)
```

Edit (New Error Code):

```
05-07 14:24:30.046: W/dalvikvm(17284): threadid=21: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
05-07 14:24:30.046: E/AndroidRuntime(17284): Uncaught handler: thread ModernAsyncTask #4 exiting due to uncaught exception
05-07 14:24:30.057: E/AndroidRuntime(17284): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-07 14:24:30.057: E/AndroidRuntime(17284):    at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$3.done(ModernAsyncTask.java:137)
05-07 14:24:30.057: E/AndroidRuntime(17284):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
05-07 14:24:30.057: E/AndroidRuntime(17284):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
05-07 14:24:30.057: E/AndroidRuntime(17284):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
05-07 14:24:30.057: E/AndroidRuntime(17284):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
05-07 14:24:30.057: E/AndroidRuntime(17284):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
05-07 14:24:30.057: E/AndroidRuntime(17284):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
05-07 14:24:30.057: E/AndroidRuntime(17284):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
05-07 14:24:30.057: E/AndroidRuntime(17284): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to acquire a reference on a close SQLiteClosable
05-07 14:24:30.057: E/AndroidRuntime(17284):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:31)
  05-07 14:24:30.057: E/AndroidRuntime(17284):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:56)
 05-07 14:24:30.057: E/AndroidRuntime(17284):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
 05-07 14:24:30.057: E/AndroidRuntime(17284):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:49)
 05-07 14:24:30.057: E/AndroidRuntime(17284):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1221)
 05-07 14:24:30.057: E/AndroidRuntime(17284):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1194)
 05-07 14:24:30.057: E/AndroidRuntime(17284):   at com.webnation.gpstracking.SQLiteCursorLoader.buildCursor(SQLiteCursorLoader.java:54)
 05-07 14:24:30.057: E/AndroidRuntime(17284):   at com.webnation.gpstracking.AbstractCursorLoader.loadInBackground(AbstractCursorLoader.java:38)
  05-07 14:24:30.057: E/AndroidRuntime(17284):  at com.webnation.gpstracking.AbstractCursorLoader.loadInBackground(AbstractCursorLoader.java:1)
 05-07 14:24:30.057: E/AndroidRuntime(17284):   at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:240)
 05-07 14:24:30.057: E/AndroidRuntime(17284):   at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:51)
 05-07 14:24:30.057: E/AndroidRuntime(17284):   at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:40)
 05-07 14:24:30.057: E/AndroidRuntime(17284):   at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$2.call(ModernAsyncTask.java:123)
 05-07 14:24:30.057: E/AndroidRuntime(17284):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

My rawSQL parameter does ask for the _id column, so I'm not sure what's happening there.

I've done some research and most of it says that you need to close databases and cursors in a particular order.  Since I'm using a custom cursor loader (SqliteCursorLoader) that retrieves data from a database, I am not sure how to do this.

Here is my onActivityCreated:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    gps = new GPSTracker(getActivity());
    mGPSDC = new GPSDateCoordinates();
    CalcDate();
    //enables buttons for next and previous months
    GetPreviousFollowingMonths();
    adapter= new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row, null, new String[] {
            myDbHelper.COLUMN_DISTANCE, myDbHelper.COLUMN_FORMATTEDSTART }, 
            new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.value },0);
    lvReports.setAdapter(adapter);

    btnDate.setText(getMonth(BaseMonth) + " " + String.valueOf(BaseYear));
    getSherlockActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);


    // show location button click event
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                CalculatePreviousNextMonths(false);
                //getSherlockActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_ID, null, ReportsFragment.this);
                getSherlockActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(LOADER_ID).forceLoad();
                GetPreviousFollowingMonths();  
                btnDate.setText(getMonth(BaseMonth) + " " + String.valueOf(BaseYear));

        }
    });

    // show location button click event
    btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View arg0) {
                 CalculatePreviousNextMonths(true);
                 //getSherlockActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_ID, null, ReportsFragment.this);
                 getSherlockActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(LOADER_ID).forceLoad();
                 GetPreviousFollowingMonths();  
                 btnDate.setText(getMonth(BaseMonth) + " " + String.valueOf(BaseYear));

         }
    });


}
```

Here is the rest of the fragment containing the Loader functions;

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {

    loader = new SQLiteCursorLoader(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), myDbHelper,
            myDbHelper.getSQLArrayOfDatesDistances(BaseYear,BaseMonth),null);
    return loader;

}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor cursor) {
    adapter.changeCursor(cursor);

}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
    adapter.changeCursor(null);

}
```

Comment: When and where are you calling `close()` on your `SQLiteOpenHelper`?

Comment: Every time I open the database, I am closing it.  I just checked my code to be sure.  The call to myDbHelper.getSQLArrayOfDatesDistances(BaseYear,BaseMonth) returns only raw sql, does not touch the database.

Comment: Updated error logs in question.

Comment: "Every time I open the database, I am closing it" -- that's not an especially helpful answer. Certainly, your second stack trace suggests that you are closing the `SQLiteOpenHelper` before you are done with the database. While closing a database is certainly good form, since it is not essential, I'd start by getting rid of your close-the-database logic for the time being.

Comment: That did it.  I just commented out those lines and now everything is working.

Comment: Now I am getting "Leak Found" notices.  Back to the drawing board.